# How to add custom HTML tag TSX

Tags: tsx, custom-tag

While trying to render a custom HTML tag `<my-element>` in JSX an error displayed
**Property does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'**

I've found some examples of how to do that using

```js
declare global {
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    "my-element": any
  }
}
```

but this produced another error:

> ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces  @typescript-eslint/no-namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the useful link to [Typescript guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) which helped me a lot:

The main idea is to create a new file with extension **d.ts** (e.g. myModule.d.ts) which should contain the following

```js
export as namespace JSX;

export interface IntrinsicElements {
  "my-element": any;
}
```